# How can I select multiple values from many tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to SELECT PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, HARDWARE_ID and SOFTWARE_ID which are all linked in a table ASSIGNMENTS, but I want to show that link while also showing all the attributes in each respective table linked to the relevant ID (e.g STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE from the STAFF table). Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PROJECT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_NAME CHAR(20),
PROJECT_TYPE CHAR(20),
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID));

CREATE TABLE HARDWARE
(HARDWARE_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
HARDWARE_NAME CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (HARDWARE_ID));

CREATE TABLE SOFTWARE
(SOFTWARE_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
SOFTWARE_NAME CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (SOFTWARE_ID));

CREATE TABLE STAFF
(STAFF_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
STAFF_NAME CHAR(20),
JOB_TYPE CHAR(20),
JOB_GRADE CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_ID));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENTS
(ASSIGNMENT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_ID CHAR(5),
STAFF_ID CHAR(5),
HARDWARE_ID CHAR(5),
SOFTWARE_ID CHAR(5),
PRIMARY KEY (ASSIGNMENT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (STAFF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF(STAFF_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (HARDWARE_ID) REFERENCES HARDWARE(HARDWARE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (SOFTWARE_ID) REFERENCES SOFTWARE(SOFTWARE_ID));
```

Here is some basic data:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES ('B0001','BIKESHOP.COM','WEB DEVELOPMENT',TO_DATE('15/01/17','DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('15/02/17','DD/MM/YY'));

INSERT INTO HARDWARE (HARDWARE_ID, HARDWARE_NAME)
VALUES ('H0001','WEBDEV PC1');

INSERT INTO SOFTWARE (SOFTWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_NAME)
VALUES ('S0001','COFFEECUP IDE');

INSERT INTO STAFF (STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE)
VALUES ('ST001','JOHN MASON','WEB DEVELOPER','1');

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENTS (ASSIGNMENT_ID, PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, HARDWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_ID)
VALUES ('A0001','B0001','ST001','H0001','S0001');
```

How can I SELECT all attributes from all tables linked to a single PROJECT_ID to show for example:

```
PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, START_DATE, END_DATE, STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE, HARDWARE_ID, HARDWARE_NAME, SOFTWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_NAME 
as one row, all linked to PROJECT_ID = 'B0001'.
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question you posted 1 hour ago?

Comment: It is albeit slightly updated to make it more clear. Sorry for the duplicate, I just didn't yet understand fully how to do it from the previous question's answers.

Comment: If an answer to a question is not clear, add a comment to the answer to ask for some clarifications, or simply wait for a clearer one. Posting twice the same question is not the rigth way. Given that you accepted an answer here, please close the other question.

Comment: Please learn to edit your posts, Having multiple versions of the same question creates confusion and wastes other people's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, you need the exact query spelled out for you. Here you go:

```
select p.*,
    s.*,
    h.*,
    sf.*
from assignments a
inner join staff s on a.staff_id = s.staff_id
inner join software sf on a.software_id = sf.software_id
inner join hardware h on a.hardware_id = h.hardware_id
inner join project p on a.project_id = p.project_id
where a.project_id = 'A0001';
```

Comment: Thank you! My SQL Developer isn't working properly now so I can't check if it worked for me but I would imagine it does, I'll check ASAP.

Comment: This solution is exactly what the OP asked for. However it is worth noting that the projection will include duplicate columns (`assignments staff_id` and `staff.staff_id`, etc). There is no way to avoid such duplication except by explicitly naming columns in the projection (which is good practice anyway).